# Ajax zend framework 2

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework2

I'm using ajax in my ZF2 Application and I have a problem with Ajax. My code is this:

Ajax:

```
$('.checkbox-published').on('click', function () {
        var id_entity = "";
        var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");

        var path = $(this).attr('url');
        id_entity = $(this).val();
        alert(path);
        $.ajax({
            url: path,
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: {'id_entity': $(this).val(), 'ischecked': ischecked},
            success: function (data, status) {
                alert("Succes + info: " + data.message);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (xhr.status === 0) {
                    alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                } else if (xhr.status == 404) {
                    alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                } else if (xhr.status == 500) {
                    alert('Server Error [500].');
                } else if (errorThrown === 'parsererror') {
                    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                } else if (errorThrown === 'timeout') {
                    alert('Time out error.');
                } else if (errorThrown === 'abort') {
                    alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                } else {
                    alert('There was some error. Try again.');
                }
            },
        });
    });
```

And my controller:

```
public function publishAjaxAction()
{
    $result = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'There was some error. Try again.');
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $locale = $this->locale();

        $data['id_entity'] = $request->getPost('id_entity');
        $data['ischecked'] = $request->getPost('ischecked');
        $result['message'] = "Animo que funciona!" . $data['id_entity'] . "->" . $data['ischecked'];
        $dataToTable = array(
            'id' => $data['id_entity'],
            'locale' => $locale,
            'ischecked' => $data['ischecked'],
        );

        $this->getCenterTable()->publishEntity($dataToTable);
    }

    return new JsonModel($result);
}
```

It don't retunrs any data. If it works it will return a message with there was some error. But what I have in my response is undefined. I don't know how to solve it.

Any help would be perfect.

Comment: Have you set up the JsonStrategy in config file ?

Comment: can you do console.log(data); what do you get ?